# Incremental data extraction Adobe AEM query builder

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6, aem-63

I have recently started to work on Adobe AEM. I have a few set of queries that I use to extract data from AEM. I was wondering is there any way to get only incremental data. I mean new and only updated data from AEM. I would have posted queries but being a client entity, I am not allowed to share. I request to be assisted for the same. Even if you point me to the right resource, it will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: What about adding a date to the query, so you get the results after a certain date?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can form querybuilder query with date property
for example:

```
type=cq:PageContent
path=/content/we-retail/us/en

daterange.property=cq:lastModified
daterange.lowerBound=2021-05-28T00:00:00.000+02:00
daterange.lowerOperation=>=
```

above query will give us the pages modified after 28th Man 2021.